# Creating an array from a text file in java

Tags: java, arrays

I know how to create arrays like so:

```
int[] myIntArray = new int[]{1,2,3};
```

My question is this. What if I had a file, titled Lab11Input.txt, and filled it with integer values. How would I go about creating a method that opens the file, counts the number of numbers in the file, creates the array, then fills the array with the values from the file?

For example, if I pass in Lab11Input.txt as an argument, could I do it that way?

Comment: Show us an extract of the file please

Comment: It's just a common txt file, with each line containing a integer.

Comment: Perhaps you should make an effort at doing your homework assignment first and then come back here if you have questions.

Comment: Did you read the question? I know how to declare arrays if you list the values right beside it, but I'm not sure how to create them if the values are in another file.

Answer (score 2):

A simple way using [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html):

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File ("Lab11Input.txt"));
List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<>();
while(sc.hasNextInt()) {
    ints.add(sc.nextInt());
}
// then you can convert ints to an array
```